# How do I add a QWidget designed in Qt Designer inside a designed QMainWindow?

Tags: qt, pyqt4, pyside

I started developing an application, I designed a empty QMainWindow wit just the menu bar. and created two new QWidgets and designed the features of my application on each.

Here is the thing: How do I add and interchange the last two QWidgets inside my QMainWindow?, so QMainWindow will show one set of features of my application at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [QStackedWidget](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstackedwidget.html)

(from Qt: *The QStackedWidget class provides a stack of widgets where only one widget is visible at a time.*)

---

You can find it insde the **Containers** group

[image]

Add a StackedWidget into your MainWindow, then

1. Directly edit the widget at present page by Qt designer(use the upper-right arrows to switch between differetn widgets). Notice that
   in StackedWidget you have to create another signal sender, ex: a
   combobox to decide which widget should be shown), or
2. If your custom widget contains some customized and hand-crafted
   funcationalites that Qt doesn't have, you might need  [the widget
   promotion](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/how_to_use.html#embedding-widgets-inside-pyqt-applications). (otherwise, skip this)